# Explain Java SSLServerSocket javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to set up a simple Java Client and Server that communicate with each other using Sockets but are secured using SSL. I keep getting the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

The client and server are being run on the same machine. I've done some research online and there seems to be many possible reasons and ways to attempt to fix this problem. I am reading through the error and not really understanding what is going on. Would someone be able to explain what the following error means?:

**Server Init**

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 05:00:00 BST 1999 until Mon Jun 22 05:00:00 BST 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xcf08e5c0816a5ad427ff0eb271859d0
  Valid from Tue Nov 07 19:31:18 GMT 2006 until Mon Dec 31 19:40:55 GMT 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x605949e0262ebb55f90a778a71f94ad86c
  Valid from Tue Nov 13 00:00:00 GMT 2012 until Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 GMT 2038

<<<<< MANY OTHER TRUSTED CERTS ADDED >>>>>>> 

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

**Client Attempts to Connect**

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 C3                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 195
0000: 01 00 00 BF 03 03 5A 6C   9E 84 A4 3A 54 B8 59 FD  ......Zl...:T.Y.
0010: C1 66 AC 78 DB 5F 2E 2C   10 2A 40 18 9F E7 98 DE  .f.x._.,.*@.....
0020: 59 18 5C 40 BF CE 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  Y.\@....:.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 5C 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......\...4.2...
0070: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0080: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0090: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
00A0: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   1A 00 18 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03   03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00C0: 02 01 01                                           ...
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 195
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1517002116 bytes = { 164, 58, 84, 184, 89, 253, 193, 102, 172, 120, 219, 95, 46, 44, 16, 42, 64, 24, 159, 231, 152, 222, 89, 24, 92, 64, 191, 206 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 195
0000: 01 00 00 BF 03 03 5A 6C   9E 84 A4 3A 54 B8 59 FD  ......Zl...:T.Y.
0010: C1 66 AC 78 DB 5F 2E 2C   10 2A 40 18 9F E7 98 DE  .f.x._.,.*@.....
0020: 59 18 5C 40 BF CE 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  Y.\@....:.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 5C 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......\...4.2...
0070: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0080: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0090: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
00A0: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   1A 00 18 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03   03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00C0: 02 01 01                                           ...
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Server Code**

```
public class SSLServerExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        try{
            SSLServerSocketFactory factory=(SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket=(SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(1234);

            SSLSocket sslsocket=(SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

            DataInputStream is=new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
            PrintStream os=new PrintStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
            while(true)  {
                String input=is.readUTF();
                String ketqua=input.toUpperCase();
                os.println(ketqua);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
public class SSLClientExample {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory factory=(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket=(SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("127.0.0.1",1234);

            DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream is=new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());

            String str="helloworld";
            os.writeBytes(str);

            String responseStr;
            if((responseStr=is.readUTF())!=null) {
                System.out.println(responseStr);
            }

            os.close();
            is.close();
            sslsocket.close();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the part that manages security in your code?

Comment: @Black.Jack that is all of my code. You're going to need to explain a little more

Comment: Your server doesn't have a private key, See my answer in the duplicate.

Comment: NB `readUTF()` cannot return null. Why are you testing for it?